# Nodemailer: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

Estou tentando mandar um email pelo nodemailer, mas aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

O meu código:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "---------",
        pass: "----------"
    }
})
transporter.sendMail({
    from: "-------- <--------->",
    to: "-----------",
    subject: "Teste",
    text: "teste"
})
```

Comment: segue [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088006/nodejs-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain/45088585), vai te ajudar a resolver esse problema.

Comment: Você está utilizando um certificado que não foi assinado por uma autoridade de certificação. O risco de usar esse tipo de é qualquer outra pessoa pode fazer um certificado desses. Um atacante pode interceptar o seu tráfego de dados criando um desses certificados.

Answer (score -1):

Acresenta a propriedade `tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false,}` no transporter, como abaixo:

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: "---------",
        pass: "----------"
    },
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }
})
```

Deve resolver.